# Install linux package in iso into ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apt, kernel, dpkg

here I want to ask, I am familiar with ubuntu, with unity, shortcuts, etc.

I have learned about Kali linux, I have installed Kali linux in my PC but I am not familiar with the environment,

I've had Kali linux Iso,

My Laptops is installed Ubuntu LTS 12.04,

Can I install a Kali Linux Package from iso into my ubuntu,

Comment: Not entirely sure what exactly you're trying to do - run Kali Linux inside Ubuntu or install one of Kali's packages in Ubuntu. As far as I see (not very familiar with Kali) it uses debs (?) - so theoretically, unless there are some big differences between systems it might work - but anyway, first I'd suggest to check  - maybe the software you're looking for is in Ubuntu's own repos.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to keep Ubuntu OS, you can install Kali linux within Ubuntu with a virtual machine (VirtualBox, etc), or you can create another partition and install Kali linux in that partition, so you can dual boot either to Ubuntu or Kali linux when you start the machine.